# calculate tables

Tags: tables, multicolumn, spreadtab

I have two tables which look like this

```
  \begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}p{8.5cm}|c|}}
    \hline 
    @Datum & @Tätigkeit & @Zeitaufwand [h] \\ 
    \hline \hline
    @03.11.2016 &@Beginn der Erstellung des ET-Racing Logos & 2 \\ 
    \hline 
    @04.11.2016 &@Fortsetzung der Erstellung des ET-Racing Logos & 3.5 \\ 
    \hline \hline
        @\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & @\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Zwischenzeit}} & \textbf{:={sum(c2:c3)}}  %make the sum
       \\   
     \hline     
    \end{spreadtab} 
    \caption{Zeitaufzeichnung Donner}
   \end{table}

   \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}p{8.5cm}|c|}}
        \hline 
        @Datum & @Tätigkeit & @Zeitaufwand [h] \\ 
        \hline \hline
        @19.11.2017 & @Dokumentieren und zeichnen& 4\\
        \hline
        @21.09.2017  &@Besprechung - Kostenaufstellung & 0.5\\
        \hline
        @09.10.2017 & @Dokumentieren & 2\\
        \hline
        @28.10.2017 & @Berechnung - Momentenübersetzung & 3\\
        \hline \hline
        @\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & @\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Zwischenzeit}} & \textbf{:={sum(c2:c5)}} %make the sum 
    \\     
         \hline     
    \end{spreadtab} 
    \caption{Zeitaufzeichnung Donner}
\end{table}

    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|>{\centering}p{8.5cm}|c|}}
        \hline 
        @Datum & @Tätigkeit & @Zeitaufwand [h] \\ 
        \hline \hline
        @15.01.2018 & @DC/DC Wandler ausmessen und testen & 2\\
        \hline
        @21.01.2018 & @Dokumentationsfeature hinzugefügt & 3\\
        \hline
        @22.01.2018 & @Handysensoren (Android) auslesen, mittels Simulink & 4\\
        \hline \hline
        @\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & @\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Zwischenzeit}} & \textbf{:={sum(c2:c4)}}  %make the sum 
     \\    
       \hline       
    \end{spreadtab} 
    \caption{Zeitaufzeichnung Donner}
\end{table}
```

In the lines, where i added the comment "make the sum" TeX is writing the sum from the table. Now i want to create a 4th table which sums up the sums from the tables above. Can anyone show me how its done

(Sorry for my broken english)

Thanks in advance
Xandl

Comment: Please tell us which (La)TeX format you use (pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX?), which document class you employ, and which packages you load.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. Ideally it should compile  unless, of course, that is what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\STsavecell` to save a cell value in macro and then use that macro to place a value in a subsequent table.  The `\STsavecell` mechanism is used as follows:

```
\begin{spreadtab}[\STsavecell{\totone}{c4}]{{tabular}{ccc}}
   ...
\end{spreadtab}
```

saving the result in cell `c4` in the macro `\totone`.  You can then place this in spreadtab cell via

```
:={\totone}
```

Putting this together in your example gives

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{spreadtab,array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{spreadtab}[\STsavecell{\totone}{c4}]{{tabular}{c>{\centering}p{8.5cm}c}}
    \toprule
    @Datum & @Tätigkeit & @Zeitaufwand [h] \\
    \midrule
    @03.11.2016 &@Beginn der Erstellung des ET-Racing Logos & 2 \\
    @04.11.2016 &@Fortsetzung der Erstellung des ET-Racing Logos & 3.5 \\
    \midrule
    &@\textbf{Zwischenzeit} & \textbf{:={sum(c2:c3)}} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{spreadtab}
  \caption{Zeitaufzeichnung Donner}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{spreadtab}[\STsavecell{\tottwo}{c6}]{{tabular}{c>{\centering}p{8.5cm}c}}
    \toprule
    @Datum & @Tätigkeit & @Zeitaufwand [h] \\
    \midrule
    @19.11.2017 & @Dokumentieren und zeichnen& 4\\
    @21.09.2017  &@Besprechung - Kostenaufstellung & 0.5\\
    @09.10.2017 & @Dokumentieren & 2\\
    @28.10.2017 & @Berechnung - Momentenübersetzung & 3\\
    \midrule
    & @\textbf{Zwischenzeit} & \textbf{:={sum(c2:c5)}} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{spreadtab}
  \caption{Zeitaufzeichnung Donner}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{spreadtab}[\STsavecell{\totthree}{c5}]{{tabular}{c>{\centering}p{8.5cm}c}}
    \toprule
    @Datum & @Tätigkeit & @Zeitaufwand [h] \\
    \midrule
    @15.01.2018 & @DC/DC Wandler ausmessen und testen & 2\\
    @21.01.2018 & @Dokumentationsfeature hinzugefügt & 3\\
    @22.01.2018 & @Handysensoren (Android) auslesen, mittels Simulink & 4\\
    \midrule
    &@\textbf{Zwischenzeit}& \textbf{:={sum(c2:c4)}} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{spreadtab}
  \caption{Zeitaufzeichnung Donner}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{lc}}
    \toprule
    @Table One&:={\totone}\\
    @Table Two&:={\tottwo}\\
    @Tabel Three&:={\totthree}\\
    \midrule
    @Grand Total&:={sum(b1:b3)}\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{spreadtab}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Incidentially, using `[h!]` placement option probably means you shouldn't be using a floating `table` environment.  Either let the tables float, or use `center` combined with the `captionof` package to add captions.